# How to set the default image to UIButton in Viewdidload in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I try to set Image for a UIButton. But how to set the default image for UIButton ?

The code of UIButton in header file is like the following.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *modeChangeButton;
```

And I try to set the image size and default image for UIButton , but it doesn't show the image. The code is like the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.modeChangeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 450, 60, 60)];
    [self.modeChangeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recordmode.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

how to set the default image for UIButton ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you declare the button with IBOutlet, it should be loaded from storyboard or xib , why you create another uibutton instance ? If you didn't load the button from storyboard or xib , why didn't you add the button on the `self.view`.

Comment: Did you duplicate your own question?    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378603/why-the-sender-not-called-when-i-click-the-image-of-the-button-in-objective-c/23378773#23378773

Comment: see the answers given on other question!

Comment: If you are creating button with storyboard than you can set image of button from attribute inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `IBOutlet`, you no need to reallocate your button. Please try as below

Using IBOutlet :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.modeChangeButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 450, 60, 60);

    [self.modeChangeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recordmode.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Using Programmatically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.modeChangeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 450, 60, 60)];
    [self.modeChangeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recordmode.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [self.view addSubView:self.modeChangeButton];
}
```

Also, Check your Y position of your button. Whether it is out of view frame.

Comment: Excuse me...but the `self.modeChangeButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 450, 60, 60);` seem didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add your button as a subview.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.modeChangeButton];
```

Comment: I have create a button in xib . If I use addSubview , it will add the new button.

Comment: `[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 450, 60, 60)]` gives you a BRAND NEW BUTTON. Don't make a new one if you don't intend to add it as a subview.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.modeChangeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 450, 60, 60)];
    [self.modeChangeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recordmode.png"]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

You have missed calling `viewDidLoad` of super. I am guess that might be the issue.

Comment: I have calling viewDidLoad of super , just didn't past here.

Comment: @Wun You can expect to get more answers like this if you don't post ALL relevant code.